# How can I activate a popup animation for the lightbox in the Betheme WordPress theme when clicked?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

How can I add a custom animation to the lightbox feature in the Betheme by muffingroup when a picture is clicked? Currently, the lightbox enlarges the image and applies a semi-transparent grey background, but I would like to incorporate an additional animation when the lightbox opens. Although the theme builder offers entrance or hover animations, I am unsure of how to add a custom animation using CSS and JavaScript. Specifically, which CSS rules should be defined and where should I attach the new class via JavaScript? If anyone has experience with customizing existing themes or has expertise with the Betheme, your assistance would be greatly appreciated.

While exploring the examples and documentation provided by the developers of Betheme, particularly the image documentation available at https://muffingroup.com/betheme/elements/image/, I noticed a lack of instructions on how to incorporate an onclick animation. In fact, I am beginning to doubt if their theme even includes such a feature. Despite my efforts, I have been unable to find any relevant information on how to add an onclick animation to the lightbox functionality.